# Bind keeps resigning one zone and sending updates

Tags: bind, dnssec

I have multiple zones on a master NS server, which transfer to public faced servers.
But after enabling DNSSEC for every zone, one zone continues doing IXFR (has been doing it for 2 weeks now), every 1-3 minutes, incrementing the serial.

I see lines like these in the logs:

```
zone mydomain.xyz/IN (signed): sending notifies (serial 2024043409)
client ns1#37177 (mydomain.xyz): transfer of 'mydomain.xyz/IN': IXFR started (serial 2024043408 -> 2024043409)
client ns1#37177 (mydomain.xyz): transfer of 'mydomain.xyz/IN': IXFR ended: 1 messages, 28 records, 2828 bytes, 0.001 secs (2828000 bytes/sec) (serial 2024043409)
```

My zone definition:

```
zone "mydomain.xyz" IN {
        type master;
        file "mydomain.xyz.zone";
        allow-update {
                key certbot;
        };
        key-directory "/etc/bind/keys/mydomain.xyz";
        inline-signing yes;
        dnssec-policy default;
};
```

What can be the reason for this IXFR spam?